# Find the integral of the vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vectors

> Let the vector field
>   $$\vec{F}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}{x_1^2+2x_3}\\ x_1x_2\\
>  x_3^2-2x_1\end{pmatrix}$$ Compute the integral $\int _C\vec{F}\left(\vec{x}\right)d\vec{x}$ from the origin to the point
>   $P(1/2/3)$ if $C$ is a straight line from the origin to $P$.

So in the book they only give us answers, but not how to get the answers. I calculated the integral and got

$$\int _0^112t^2-8t$$ which equals to zero, however in the book the answers is $9\frac{2}{3}$. I think the book is wrong because I just don't see how we can get that answer. Or am I wrong?

Comment: it is $9\frac23=6$ or there is some notation issue there?

Comment: It just says $9\frac{2}{\:3}\:$. I dont think it equals to 6.@Masacroso

Comment: I could also show how I got it via Photo, I think it would take me too long to type it all out :(

Comment: I had a mistake in my previous calculations (I wrote $z^3$ instead of $z^2$), but it seems that it is correct now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that $F(x,y,z)=(x^2+2z,xy,z^2-2x)$, and you want to evaluate

$$\int_C F(x,y,z)\cdot (dx,dy,dz)$$

where $C$ is the straight line parametrized by $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^3,\,t\mapsto t P$ for $P:=(1,2,3)$. Hence

$$\int_C F(x,y,z)\cdot (dx,dy,dz)=\int_0^1 (F\circ \gamma)(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)\, dt\\
=\int_0^1 (t^2+6t)\, dt+2\int_0^12t^2\, dt+3\int_0^1 (9t^2-2t)\, dt\\
=\frac13+3+2\frac23+3\left(3-1\right)=\frac53+9$$

Comment: Why is $[0,1]$?

Comment: @manooooh you can parametrize as you want. I choose parametrize using the interval $[0,1]$ because the calculus are easier

Comment: Oh I see now, so I did make a mistake then? Because I did it all together and did not split them up. $\int _0^1\begin{pmatrix}t^2-6t\\ 2t^2\\ 9t^2-2t\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 3\end{pmatrix}dt$    edit:oml I see my mistake now, I didn't multiply them. xD

Comment: Ok but then your answer would be $32/3$? I guess I must recheck because I got $\int _0^127t^2-6t+4t^2+t^2-6t=14/3$

Comment: @Naochi yes, $\frac{32}3=\frac53+9$, this is the result. I checked my answer using Wolfram Mathematica (assuming the data of the problem is correct)

Comment: Ok super thanks haha If it were not for you I would not have noticed it :)